# How to consume DLQ messages via spring cloud stream

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I want to consume kafka messages from dlq and process them. Default configuration for them is to add a listener for dlq.

Problem: I want to manually(conditional) consume message whenever i get the alert for dlq message. ANy solution from stream listener?

Comment: Not sure I fully understand. Getting an alert for a message that is in the DLQ would require some other notification mechanism (i.e., another message. . .). Isn't the message on DLQ is enough? You have a listener and once message ends up in DLQ (that in itself is notification) you process it. What am i missing?

Comment: Thanks for the response, Once message is in DLQ, question is about processing, DLQ listener will pick it instantly and process it using stream listener This is something i want to stop and process the dlq message based on a condition. is their any utility available for doing the same. What i am currently thinking is to create a service and then use KafakConsume to manually pick dlq message and then process? Any alternative in spring cloud data stream?

Comment: Consider looking into [Polling Consumer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Fishtown.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-streams-overview-using-polled-consumers). This is how you control when to poll. You can also get more info from [Gary's blog](https://spring.io/blog/2018/02/27/spring-cloud-stream-2-0-polled-consumers) on it.